# Mapping Application for Middle East

Tags: winforms, mapping, gis, mappoint

We have a desktop application that has been using MapPoint for displaying data on a European map. We now want to support Middle East maps, but MapPoint only support North America and Europe. Is there any other alternative to MapPoint that can be easily integrated in a .NET based Win Forms application?

Comment: @Faraz, just a side note, but creating maps in the Middle East can be a very dangerous business... how exactly are you planning to handle disputed borders and disputed names? Even if you are using someone else's API to show the map, most users won't know that, and it could get you into trouble with various clients.

Comment: @Michael: We are only interested in maps of urban areas, far from any disputed borders. Basically, it is a vehicle tracking application, and  we expect the vehicles to be within large urban areas.

But you have raised a very valid point. We will be sure to keep this into consideration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might consider evaluating openstreetmap data for the middle east. http://www.openstreetmap.org. They use a tiling schema that you might be able to integrate f.i. with sharpmap http://sharpmap.codeplex.com/ I am sure the sharpmap community would be pleased if someone would write an adapter for OpenStreetMap tiles.